# I have a procedure that check the temp and shows 1 of 2 messages. When the temp is low it cont to the next function?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import glob
import time
import tkMessageBox
import tkFont
```

This is where the issue is I believe:

```
def lowTempMsg(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('TEMP ERROR')
        top.geometry("300x200+100+200")
        Message(top,bg="yellow", foreground="black", text= "Temperature too Low - Reheat",font=("Ariel",20), padx=20, pady=20).pack()
        top.after(2000,lambda:top.destroy())
        self.cureTemp.delete(0,END)
        self.cureTemp.focus()

def rejMsg(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('REJECTED')
        top.geometry("300x200+100+200")
        Message(top,bg="red", foreground="white", text= "Product Characteristics out of Tolerance - Scan Reject Code",font=("Ariel",20), padx=20, pady=20).pack()
        top.after(2000,lambda:top.destroy())
        self.rejCode.focus()
def elecRejMsg(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('Rejected')
        top.geometry("300x200+100+200")
        Message(top,bg="red", foreground="white", text= "Product Characteristics out of Tolerance - Scan Reject Code",font=("Ariel",20), padx=20, pady=20).pack()
        top.after(4000,lambda:top.destroy())
        self.rejCode.focus()
```

Call to the validation:

```
        self.labelCureTemp=Label(self.master, text="Cure Temp",font=("Ariel",20),foreground="blue").grid(row=2)
        self.cureTemp = Entry(self.master,width=10,font=("Ariel",20),foreground="white", background="blue")
        self.cureTemp.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky=W,pady=40)
        self.cureTemp.bind("<FocusOut>",self.tempValid)

        self.labelRejCode=Label(self.master,text='Reject Code',font=("Ariel",20)).grid(row=14,sticky=W)
        self.rejCode=Entry(self.master,width=50,font=("Ariel",20),background="red")
        self.rejCode.grid(row=14, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W)
        #self.t.bind("<FocusOut>",self.s.focus)

    def tempValid(self, cureTemp):
        temp = int(self.cureTemp.get())

        if temp <= 219:
                return lowTempMsg(self)
        elif temp >= 261:
                return rejMsg(self)
        else:
                return()
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] that actually explains what the problem is.

Comment: In the procedure tempValid I am validating that the temp is valid.  When it is low I have it return a message and then delete and focus back to the cureTemp field to be re entered, if it is high it goes directly to rejCode.  If the temp is neither too high or too low it moves to the elecTest.  Everything works except the tempLowMsg delete and focus.

Comment: Then please cut the code down to focus on that. You've posted an awful lot to expect people to trawl through.

Comment: Pretty sure `Ariel` -> `Arial`

Answer (score 0):

```
def tempValid(self, cureTemp):
      temp = int(self.cureTemp.get())

      if temp <= 219:
          self.delete_and_focus()
          return lowTempMsg(self)
      elif temp >= 261:
          return rejMsg(self)
      else:
          return()
```

Comment: I tried that and received the error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/Code Re-Write/Final_Cure_REV4.py", line 207, in tempValid
    self.delete_and_focus()
AttributeError: MainApp instance has no attribute 'delete_and_focus'

Comment: I just realized its printing both the lowTempMsg and the rejMsg when the temp is low

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you've changed and why. Also `return` is a statement, not a function, the parentheses on the last line are redundant at best (and confusing at worst).

Comment: I added the self.delete_and_focus().  If the temp is low I want it to return the lowTempMsg, if it is high I want it to return the rejMsg.  The issue is when the temp is low(<=219) it returns both messages. I need it to run lowTempMsg then stop.

Comment: Ok - Narrowed it down to - After it calls the lowTempMsg for some reson it goes to the next field and calls the next function(elecTest